# how to suppress FATAL output from ssh on perl using the "system" call?

Tags: perl, ssh, message, suppress

I'm trying to write a simple script that uses ssh, but I want to test that ssh is working first -if it doesnt work I want to know why it's not working.

Here is what I'm trying:

```
my $output = system("ssh -q -o ConnectionTimeout=3 -o BatchMode=yes $host \"echo $host\"");
my $real_output = $output/256;
if($real_output == 2){print "RESPONSE: $host is not working, No address associated to the name \n";}
elsif($real_output == 255){print "RESPONSE: $host is not working (connection timed out after 3 secs, it exists but does not respond) \n";}
```

This works: it collects the error and tests the connection, but when I run it; it shows the following when the name of the host does not exist:

```
./testMachines --n invalid_host
warning: Connecting to invalid_host failed: No address associated to the name
RESPONSE: invalid_host is not working, No address associated to the name
```

or when the host name does exist but it's timing out:

```
./testMachines --n timeout_host
ssh: FATAL: Connection timed out.  No protocol greeting received in 10 seconds.
RESPONSE: timeout_host is not working (connection timed out after 3 secs, it exists but does not respond)
```

How do I suppress the "ssh: FATAL" and "warning" messages? I was under the impression that the '-q' option for ssh will do the trick, but it didnt.

I've also tried the '-q -q' option on ssh (as suggested on the man pages) but no luck.

I've also tried this:

```
my $output = system("ssh -q -o ConnectionTimeout=3 -o BatchMode=yes $host \"echo 2>&1\"");
```

without any luck... any ideas?

Basically what I want is the output to be like this (without the FATAL and warning ssh messages):

```
# ./testMachines -n host
RESPONSE: host is not working (connection timed out after 3 secs, it exists but does not respond)
```

Thanks a lot!!!

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you got the idea to add all that escaping, but this should work:

```
my $output = system("ssh -q -o ConnectionTimeout=3 -o BatchMode=yes $host \"echo $host\" 2>/dev/null");
```

Comment: Too much escaping! `system qq/ssh -q -o ConnectionTimeout=3 -o BatchMode=yes $host "echo $host" 2>&1/` ;-)

Comment: @Michael Slade , sorry for all the escaping I was trying to debug .. just tried your suggestion but the "warning" error still shows as follows: `# ./testMachines -n invalid_host`

**warning: Connecting to invalid_host failed: No address associated to the name**
**RESPONSE: invalid_host is not working (No address associated to the name)**         
I want only the _RESPONSE_ part

Comment: @mob ...  
Not sure what you meant by those _"qq/"_  
I tried this based on your answer:  
`my $output = system(ssh -q -o ConnectionTimeout=3 -o BatchMode=yes $host "echo $host" 2>&1);`  
But this are the errors I get:  
 `./testMachines -n invalid_host
Bareword found where operator expected at ./testMachines line 57, near "q -o ConnectionTimeout=3 -o"
        (Do you need to predeclare q?)
Number found where operator expected at ./testMachines line 57, near ""echo $host" 2"
     (Missing operator before  2?)
syntax error at ./testMachines line 57, near "q -o ConnectionTimeout=3 -o BatchMode"`

Comment: @all just tried this:  
`my $output = system("ssh -q -o ConnectionTimeout=3 -o BatchMode=yes $host \"echo $host\" 2>&1");`  
but still showing the FATAL and warning erros :s

Comment: @Michael Slade - did you mean `2>/dev/null`?

Comment: Oh crap! I somehow got the idea that OP was using ``'s!

Comment: Awesome, that `my $output = system("ssh -q -o ConnectionTimeout=3 -o BatchMode=yes $host \"echo $host\" 2>/dev/null");` did the work! :) Thanks a lot to both of you!!